# Resource for iPhone Javascript events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-events

Can any one tell me where to find the list of Javascript events like `touchstart`, `touchmove` for the iPhone and iPad devices?

Is there is any book available for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's developer site has documentation for all the additions they have made to the DOM, and specifically for touch events.

- [Safari DOM Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariJSRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001482)
- [TouchEvent Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/TouchEventClassReference/TouchEvent/TouchEvent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009358)